# delegate bean destroy method

Tags: java, spring

I have `@Configuration` class that creates `@Bean` which is `Map` that contains EventConsumers

```
//simplified code
@Bean
public Map<Long, EventConsumer> eventConsumerToIdMapping(@Value("${core.maxEventBatchSize}") int maxEventBatchSize) {
    final Map<Long, EventConsumer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Set<Long> ids : configs) {
        final EventConsumer eventConsumer = createEventConsumer(maxEventBatchSize);
        for (Long id : ids) {
            map.put(id, eventConsumer);
        }
    }
    return map;
}

private EventConsumer createEventConsumer(int maxEventBatchSize, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    final EventConsumer eventConsumer = new EventConsumer(maxEventBatchSize, threadFactory);
    eventConsumer.initialize();
    return eventConsumer;
}
```

`EventConsumer` is custom class that have destroy method that releases internal resources

```
@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {...}
```

recently I found this code does not release resources during integration tests, my tests uses
`@DirtiesContext(methodMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.BEFORE_METHOD, hierarchyMode = DirtiesContext.HierarchyMode.CURRENT_LEVEL)`
and `@Configuration` is destroyed after each test as it should be, but it does not destroy EventConsumer's, and they stay in memory

[image]

I tried adding `@Bean(destroyMethod = "clear")` but it did not help

what is a best aproach to force destroyiong those `EventConsumer` instances ?

---

one posible solution is to collect those EventConsumer in list field in `Configuration` class and call destroy on elements of this list in `Configuration` `@PreDestroy` method, but i dont like this maybe there is a better solution

Comment: `Map<Long, EventConsumer > map = new HashMap<Long, EventConsumer >() {@Override public void clear() {values().forEach(EventConsumer:: destroy);super.clear();}};`, however, I would change a design.

Comment: Make the consumers beans or write a bean that implements `DisposableBean` inject the `Map` into it and when the `destroy` method is called will iterate over the `EventConsumer` values and call the `destroy` method on it.